# Responsive facebook embed video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a facebook video embed responsive, since facebook has a "fixed" size, however it does not adapt to the size of the screen.

When I put "auto" in the width of facebook, depending on the video it leaves the height much larger than normal, as shown below (leaves the height at 1100, being normal of it is 770)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/?prefill_href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Frobertdowneyjr%2Fvideos%2F665148873653581%2F#configurator

Because multiple videos of different sizes will be included, it is not possible to leave a fixed size on some external div.

Comment: You can add custom classes to the video! - Check the docs out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player they give you samples on how to customise embedded videos.

Comment: @NiallMaher how to do that? You can add class to the wrapper div, but not to the video itself. You can only set width attribute, but it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now Facebook supports responsive video embed

```html
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
<div class="fb-video"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=10155278547321729"
    data-width="auto"
    data-show-captions="false">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work! It just shows a blank page. No error in console.

Comment: Worked fine.Thanks

Comment: @NikitaGupta can you share a bit more, the guys here are incredibly helpful :)

Comment: is this work for facebook fanpage as well...?

Comment: @gumuruh try it and share

Answer (score 12):

Add a container Div around your video:

HTML

```
<div class="facebook-responsive">
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/videosource" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.facebook-responsive {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.facebook-responsive iframe {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Use the container around your div to control it's maximum width and the set the height and width of the iframe to 100%.

Comment: Facebook videos don't always have a ratio of 56.25%. Vertical videos can have variable height ratios

Comment: Thx, works great with horizontal videos, someone more intelliuegtn than I am should maybe comment the vertical aspect ratio here!

Comment: When you copy someone's code, please give them credit. Original post: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-facebook-videos/

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, and will work with embedded IFRAME in general rather than just Facebook video. Optionally you can add "facebook-responsive-4-3" classes and such if you know the IFRAME is going to be 4:3, and the same again with other aspect ratios, adjusting the bottom padding for each.

Answer (score 3):

Add a container Div around your video:

HTML

```
<div class="facebook-responsive">
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/videosource" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
function resizeFacebookVideos() {
    var ths = $('.facebook-responsive');

    var containerWidth = ths.width();
    var iframeOldWidth = $(ths).find("iframe").width();
    var iframeOldHeight = $(ths).find("iframe").height();

    $(ths).find("iframe").attr("width", containerWidth);
    $(ths).find("iframe").attr("height", iframeOldHeight * (containerWidth / iframeOldWidth));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    resizeFacebookVideos();
});

$(window).resize(resizeFacebookVideos);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found to work -- especially in cases where I wanted to have two videos side-by-side for larger screens, using the CSS position-bottom CSS causes a miscalculation.

It seemed far easier to simply resize the videos:

```
function resizeVideos() {
  var aspectRatio = .5625;   
  var containerWidth = jQuery(".facebook-responsive").width();
  $(".facebook-responsive iframe").attr("width", containerWidth);
  $(".facebook-responsive").height(containerWidth * aspectRatio);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  resizeVideos();
});

$(window).resize(resizeVideos);
```

I did try using the Facebook SDK approach and the videos appear to adjust correctly without these changes but the load time is so painfully slow (10 seconds at least) that using iFrames still seems the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your Embedded code looks like this

```
<iframe src="/" width="734" height="824" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

**Step1:** Modify the embed code: Wrap the embed code with a div tag

```
<div class="facebook-responsive">
    <iframe src="/" width="734" height="824" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Step 2:** add the CSS in your Stylesheet files

```
.facebook-responsive {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}

.facebook-responsive iframe {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , Add a container Div around your video:

video

1- You can use mediaqueries

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .videoResponsive {
    height: whatever;
  }
}
```

2- you can use javascript

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  winWidth = $(window).width();
  $(".videoResponsive").width(winWidth*0.5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally recommend services but I've tried everything to get these to work and each has an issue with sizing or losing the post wording underneath. I use this instead. https://iframely.com/domains/facebook it works consistently.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the SDK script from Facebook itself? You can integrate with the code and add your customization for embeds. After the configuration you can copy the generated code and add to your web-site, it will be something like this:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```